# HuggingFace Trainer is not using GPU

Tags: python, huggingface-tokenizers

I wrote a simple trainer code as follows:

```
from typing import List
from tokenizers import (
    decoders,
    models,
    trainers,
    Tokenizer,
    Regex, 
    NormalizedString, 
    PreTokenizedString
)

tokenizer = Tokenizer(models.WordPiece(unk_token="[UNK]"))
special_tokens = ["[UNK]", "[PAD]", "[CLS]", "[SEP]", "[MASK]"]
trainer = trainers.WordPieceTrainer(vocab_size=2500, special_tokens=special_tokens)
tokenizer.train_from_iterator(get_training_corpus(), trainer=trainer)
```

The training process is slow, therefore I checked the GPU usage by `nvidia-smi` and found that both GPU units (I got 2 units) are idle.

The `get_training_corpus()` is basically a function that reads from an Excel file:

```
import pandas as pd

dataset = []
dataxls = pd.read_excel('data/dataset.xlsx')
for index, row in dataxls.iterrows():
    dataset.append(row['data'].strip())

def get_training_corpus():
    for i in range(0, len(dataset), 1000):
        yield dataset[i : i + 1000]
```

The code runs in JupyterHub, and the other notebooks utilize GPU without a problem. What did I miss?

The output of the GPU detection function is as follows:

```
import torch
device = "cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
print(device)
```

It prints `cuda:0`.

Comment: Did you try to move your model to the device? `device = torch.device('cuda:0')` and `model.to(device)`

Comment: Not yet, how can I make the changes in my code? Thanks.

Comment: Try to add this line at the beginning of your code `model = models.WordPiece(unk_token="[UNK]")` , then the ones I wrote in the previous comment. Finally, change your first line with `tokenizer = Tokenizer(model)`

Comment: It returns error: `AttributeError: 'tokenizers.models.WordPiece' object has no attribute 'to'`

Comment: The `WordPieceTrainer` has very limited arguments: https://huggingface.co/docs/tokenizers/api/trainers#tokenizers.trainers.WordPieceTrainer (don't even support `TrainingArguments` or `device`)